# general inequality for expectations of random variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability, inequality, random-variables

Let's suppose $X,Y \in \mathbb{R}$ denote two uniformly distributed random variables and $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a strictly increasing continuous function. I suspect that the following is true:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[f(X)] \geq \mathbb{E}[f(Y)] \implies \mathbb{E}[X] \geq \mathbb{E}[Y]
\end{equation}

So far I couldn't come up with a method for demonstrating this although I believe this must be a known result.

Comment: First I guess you mean monotone increasing… actually you mean strictly monotone increasing, right. Otherwise every constant function $f$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @Gono Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Asking that $\mathbb{E}[f(X)] \geq \mathbb{E}[f(Y)]$ for only one function $f$, whatever the properties of $f$, has little chance to imply that $\mathbb{E}[X] \geq \mathbb{E}[Y]$. Counterexamples based on two-points distributions should be easy to come by.

Comment: @Did I'm implicitly assuming that $f$ is continuous although I should probably say this.

Comment: @AidanRocke Did's point still stands. This is unlikely to be true.

Comment: Quote: "whatever the properties of f". Choose f analytic if you wish (but not f(x)=x...). More generally, let me advocate the research of counterexamples when faced with an assertion. If the search is fruitless, then and only then can one consider the assertion as plausible.

Comment: @Did Ok. How about if I assume that the random variables have a flat distribution? This was the original motivation for this question.

Comment: For a concrete (counter-)example, consider $f(x)=e^x$ and $X$ uniform on $(a,b)$ (the *flattest* distribution there is, right?), then $$E(X)=\frac12(a+b)\qquad E(f(X))=\frac{e^b-e^a}{b-a}$$ hence the property you are interested in says that, if $$\frac{e^b-e^a}{b-a}\geqslant\frac{e^d-e^c}{d-c}$$ then $$a+b\geqslant c+d$$ Still convinced this has any chance to hold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your believe is wrong… because the statement is.

e.g. take $f(x) = e^x$ then huge negative numbers are weighted "equal" because $f$ tends to $0$ very fast for $x \to -\infty$ but it does not for positive numbers because $f$ increases very fast for $x > 0$.

So $e^{-100} \approx 0$ but also $e^{-10^{18}} \approx 0$ but ofc $e^{10^{18}} \gg e^{100}$

So take $X$ with $$P(X = -10^{-18}) = P(X = 10^{-18}) = \frac{1}{2}$$ and $Y$ s.th $$P(Y = -100) = P(Y = 100 + 1) = \frac{1}{2}$$

Then: $$E[f(X)] \approx \frac{1}{2}e^{10^{18}}$$ and $$E[f(Y)] \approx \frac{1}{2}e^{100}$$ so $$E[f(X)] \gg E[f(Y)]$$ but obviously $$E[Y] = \frac{1}{2} > 0 = E[X]$$